# RxJS websocket (UI) & Stomp using Spring-websocket (backend) can work fine?

Tags: websocket, rxjs, spring-websocket, stomp, sockjs

I followed [spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) and using Stomp, sockJS (sub-protocol build on top of websocket).
I have very limited knowledge of front end and front end architect is not fine with stomp and socksJS, as his argument is why you want to add new libraries like sockjs.min.js and stomp.min.js, rather than using the existing library RxJS which also gives websocket.

**Q: Will the stomp(spring) on backend and RxJS websocket on front end(UI client) solution work?**

Note: Its not much traffic to start with, as trying this for few use cases

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your front end is using STOMP over WebSocket it doesn't really matter what client implementation you use, it should work with Spring. There are STOMP clients for RxJS and STOMP clients that don't use RxJS.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. just want to clarify that I mean front end is UI client. 
Will front end(UI client) using Websocket from RxJS and back end using Stomp over Websocket(using spring websocket library) is going to work?

Comment: As long as your front end (UI client) using WebSocket from RxJS is using a STOMP client it will work. It *must* use a STOMP client. You can't communicate with a STOMP broker (e.g. Spring) without a STOMP client.